# How to validate given Input Parameters (of Type) in Stored Procedure in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, validation, types, parameters, procedure

I need to validate the Input parameter (values sent by Front end Java application to DB procedure). For example, "User_id" input parameter has to be 5 alphanumeric with first 3 letters and last 2 numbers.("abc12", "gyh56") else raise an exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Order_mgr
IS
 PROCEDURE ins_trees (p_orders_in IN trees_t)
 IS
  BEGIN

     INSERT INTO trees (user_id, address)
     VALUES(p_orders.user_id, p_orders.address);
   END;
END;
 /
```

Object type:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE object trees_t (
        User_id VARCHAR2(10),
        Address VARCHAR2(100)
     );
```

If any User enter the "User_id" more that 5 length (or) not in 3letters 2numbers format (="abc12"), then we need to raise an exception before saving it in table.

User is allowed to enter only numbers, letters, spaces, ashes, hyphen, underscore, slash in the "Address". Anything other than that, raise an exception before saving it in table.

Please suggest and help me.

Comment: Are you familiar with Oracle's [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm) support?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_like` in your PL/SQL block using `IF` condition:

```
IF regexp_like(p_orders.user_id, '^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$') THEN

.. YOUR INSERT STATEMENT..

END IF;
```

The same way you can use other validations.

Cheers!!